# grep the string lines from the file

Tags: grep, csv, awk

csv file.

```
1,2,3,abc
2,3,4,def
3,4,5,abc
3,4,2,def
6,7,9,abc.
```

I need to read that file and get the lines of file containing abc.

Answer (score 5):

```
grep ",abc" file.csv
```

Sounds enough? Or to be sure it finishes with abc:

```
grep ",abc$" file.csv
```

(in this case the last one in your example won't match due to the full stop at the end)

Comment: +1 for the correct pattern. Don't need `cat` though: `grep ",abc" file.csv`. Another way to match just the word "abc" and not "Aabc" or "abcd" is to use word anchors: `'\<abc\>'`